# Two different formalisms of rotation matrices: the x and z are opposites

Tags: 3d, transformation, rotations

I have two different graphic representation systems that differ in the sign of the x and z vectors of the 3×3 rotation matrix.

They appear to have the same handedness (right). I have read the wikipedia articles, but I have no idea what the difference in formalism is.

On the technical side, one is handled using Python numpy, while the other uses 3js — numpy cannot handle quaternions, while 3js can, but I believe prefers Euler under the hood. Three.js has some issues with conversion of rotational matrices. So the matrix I am reporting is a 3×3 slice of the 4×4 transform matrix divided by the cubic root of its determinant (its scaling factor).

The vector representing the rotation point/translation has also got the opposite sign, but curiously if where I to display that vector the 3js system the sign I would use is the one from the other system. Also the scaling factor (camera distance) is opposite, strictly positive in 3js.

Comment: The difference is whether you are thinking of the object rotating in a fixed coordinate system or changing the coordinate system on a fixed object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow which is which. In the system where to specify a point I use the opposite of the translation matrix values the translation move the coordinate system, while in the system where I use the same translation matrix the object is moving, right?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, the problem is one of this active/alibi (moves object) or passive/alias (moves coordianate axes)? The wiki article is not too clear and I cannot figure out why the y axis seems unaffected hence my double checking.